# Multiple UIViewControllers inside UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

can not find an explanation of how to develop an app that is developed with 3 ViewControllers within a PageView. Somebody know any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/01/17/ios-swift-tutorial-uipageviewcontroller-as-user-onboarding-tool/

Comment: This tutorial only show how to change the values of only one viewcontroller, I have 4 viewcontroller files, I need to load each viewcontroller in the pageviewcontroller process

Answer (score -1):

I created a Swift tutorial on how to use `UIPageViewController` with three `View Controllers`.

It includes two sample projects -- a starter project on which to walk through the tutorial, and a final project to check your answer.

http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/need-to-create-an-onboarding-flow-for-your-mobile-app-heres-how-to-do-it-using-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift/

[image]

But here's the gist of using `UIPageViewController`:

- In `viewDidLoad`, use `setViewControllers` and pass in a single `View Controller` instantiated via `Storyboard ID`.  It takes an array, but you will always pass in just one VC
- You can't wire the `DataSource` using the `Storyboard`, so you have to do `dataSource = self`
- Now that you're the `DataSource`, you need to implement `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController`.
- For `viewControllerAfterViewController`, figure out which is the current page like so: `if viewController.isKindOfClass(PageOneClassName) { }`
- Once you know the current page, return whatever comes next by instantiating a VC from the Storyboard.  If it's the last page, just return `nil`
- For `viewControllerBeforeViewController`, just return the previous page.  Again, return `nil` if you're at the beginning.